# How to solve this gaussian derived integral?

Tags: integration, gaussian

So I am complicating some coherence problem and I wish to integrate the overlap of two wave functions with some phase induced.

The result is:
[enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/7kGBC.jpg)

In the second part, the cos replaced the complex exponential where its odd sin component cancels out over the symmetric integral. Also, a is negative and b is general.

Does anyone know what the result of this integral is? Also, I would reaaaly love to know where and/or how to be able to get the result, as I want to complicate my life even more at later times.

The point is that, originally, the integral had b=0, so it was a Gaussian with a cosine, but I do not know how to calculate this.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I'm not entirely clear on which integral you want to do, but I gather you're interested in integrals of the form

$$\int_{-\infty}^\infty d x \exp(a x^2 + b x + c)$$

where $a$ is a negative real parameter and $b,c$ are complex numbers.

The trick is to use a change of variables and complete the square, so that you have an integral of the form

$$D \int_{-\infty}^\infty d x \exp(a (x-x_0)^2)$$

and then do another change of variables to eliminate $x_0$ and use standard Gaussian integral techniques such as looking it up or transforming to a 2D integral with polar coordinates to finish the problem.

Comment: You set c and forgot to add ix to it... the two integrals are the same, as I have explained. Essentially, my problem is exactly due to the e^icx term.

Comment: Vlad Ispas: my "c" isn't the same as yours. My "b" contains your "c" because my "b" is complex. I think my "b" is the same as your b+ic.

Comment: oh yeah, my apologies.... i just saw the c missing the x dependence and jumped right at commenting... thank you so much! I will definitely follow your steps